# Integral with dm(x,y) with respect to measure: what is the difference between $\int f(x)dx$ and $\int f(x) dm(x)$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

What is the difference between $\int f(x)dx$ and $\int f(x) dm(x)$?

In an exercise I was asked to compute $\int\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}xe^{xy}dm(x,y)$ and I did it using the definition $\int f(x,y)dm(x,y)=\int\limits_0^\infty m(\{(x,y): f(x,y)>t\})dt$ but then the TA told me that $dm(x,y)$ is the same as $d\vec{(x,y)}$ and by using Tonelli (since $f(x,y)>0$ in this case) the integral is simply $\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 f(x,y)dydx$

**So my question is**: why do we use two different notations for the same thing? And what exactly is $dm(x,y)$?

Comment: Depends on the context. $dm(x)$ could denote integration with respect to an arbitrary measure $m$. The notation $dx$ usually refers to integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure. If $m$ is in particular the Lebesgue measure, then of course $dx$ and $dm(x)$ mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto xe^{xy}$ on $[0,1]^2$ is nonnegative, so by Tonelli's theorem,
$$
\iint_{[0,1]^2} xe^{xy}\ \mathsf dm(x,y)<\infty
$$
and is equal to the integrated integrals
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 xe^{xy}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 xe^{xy}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx.
$$
In general, $\mathsf d m(x,y)$ means integrating with respect to two-dimensional Lebesgue measure (in this case restricted to the cube $[0,1]^2$). Meanwhile, the iterated integrals are integration with respect to one-dimensional Lebesgue measure, performed twice in a row. These are in general not the same thing, but coincide under the assumptions of Tonelli's (or Fubini's) theorem.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it seems to only repeat my question

Comment: Okay, I added some detail. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I just don't understand why we need the notation $dm(\vec x)$ when we have $d\vec x$